# Coldfusion Query loop works in cf10 but not 9

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

Why does the following work in CF10 but not CF9?

```
<cfset out="">
<cfif isQuery( arguments.values ) >
    <cfloop query="#arguments.values#" >            
        <cfset out = '#out#<option value="#value#">#label#</option>'>
    </cfloop>
</cfif>
```

CF9 states that "Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values." for the line containing the cfloop. I'm using the Coldbox framework and it's debugger information shows that arguments.values is a query with Label & Value columns.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Prior to CF10, the query attribute of [cfloop](http://cfdocs.org/cfloop-looping-over-a-query) can only be a string - the name of the query - not the variable itself.

So, when you put `#arguments.values#` it is trying to convert the complex query object to a string, to obtain a name, which is where the error comes from.

It works in CF10 because the attribute has been updated to also allow a query value.

**side notes:**

This line of code can be simplified:

```
<cfset out = '#out#<option value="#value#">#label#</option>'>
```

to:

```
<cfset out &= '<option value="#value#">#label#</option>'>
```

Also you very likely should be using `HtmlEditFormat`* on at least label, and perhaps value too.

<sup>*(or `encodeForHtml` if it only needs to work in CF10+)</sup>

Comment: side notes: or use `cfsavecontent` to save the output to an `out` variable

Comment: Thanks Henry. Transitioned some of my code to cfsavecontent but haven't had time to move it all there yet. I like the way it works better.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the extra tip on shortening it. I 'll have to remember that one. I'm still transitioning to CF. I didn't know about the HTMLEditFormat function should solve some my other problems I run into occasionally.

Comment: @Henry I think in this situation using string concatenation as per Peter's suggesting is actually the better approach: less code and looks tidier. Obviously this is subjective though.

Comment: FYI, for concatenating large number of strings where extra whitespace doesn't matter, benchmark had shown that `cfsavecontent` is the more efficient method than `&=` . :)

Comment: I agree with adam and Henry, lol.  small output, `&=` is clean and works well, and `cfsavecontent` also is very fast for large strings.  I've also found that `"#myName# is Travis"` is faster than `myName & " is Travis"`. sadly I prefer the slower syntax. fortunately it doesn't matter unless you're dealing with very large strings or you are trying to make every millisecond count.